# Highlight path separators in PS1

Tags: bash, prompt

I want to do something like this in Bash:

[how to format the path in a zsh prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/49092/how-to-format-the-path-in-a-zsh-prompt)

But everything I try results in the `PWD` being fixed to the first directory I start my terminal in. Strangely I've also got a function in my `PS1` to put the current git branch in the prompt and that always updates so I'm confused as to why the `PWD` gets stuck. My current prompt [is here](https://github.com/ibrahima/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc.d/prompt.sh) incidentally.

I tried replacing `\w` with `$(pwd|grep --color=always /)` but that just gets stuck. I also tried doing it using a bash string replacement but that doesn't work either. `${PWD////$bldred/$bldblu}` ($bldred and $bldblu are defined in my prompt.sh).

Answer (score 1):

When including a dynamic variable in your prompt you need to quote it.

I don't quite understand some of your PROMPT_COMMAND stuff, but try `PS1='${PWD////'"$bldred/$bldblue"'} \$'` by itself and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The last part of the script:

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1=...
...
```

is useless when you've set `$PROMPT_COMMAND` - that version of `$PS1` will only run once. So you won't ever see a title update after the first run of that script. You need to add the title change in `$PROMPT_COMMAND` with everything else.

Move that `switch` inside the true branch of

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
```

and build to different `$PROMPT_COMMANDS` based on that. Works for me.

Comment: That part actually came from Ubuntu default file, wasn't aware that could be affecting it. Actually I ended up realizing that he had put the whole thing in PROMPT_COMMAND including the PS1 part and it worked.